# Select layout by user in QML application

Tags: qt, layout, qml, qt5, qt-quick

In my QML application there are many components like map, video, console and so on. I want to allow the user to change current layout of components (position and visibility). The problem is that I want each layout to be separate .qml file which reuse already existing components. For example on layout switch map should not be destroyed and instantiated again. [Here is an example of what I would like to avoid](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtquick-components-symbian-1.1/examples-native-scalability-separatelayouts.html) - each layout creates components only for themselves so layout cannot be changed. I had some experiments with reparenting components on state change but it produces a lot of code and nothing works.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you need to [use states](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdeclarativestates.html)! Each state can arrange same items in different layout. They can even re-parent items.
Now question is: can you move state description to separate file. IMO it should work. I didn't try it.

Anyway items will not be recreated so you will achieve main goal.