# QML User selectable layout

Tags: qt, qml

I am developing an app meant for desktop size touch screen display.

I am very familiar with Qt but not so much with QML yet, I've been trying to dig into it but always in small sessions because of a lack of time. This is a slow going side project involving a touch screen and QML / QtQuick seems like the right choice (.and the opportunity for me to learn about it)

The app would have many different components for different purposes and I would like the user to be able to arrange said components in the layout of their choice.

The user would be presented with a grid of buttons with icons representing different layout options such as this random example found on google:

[image: Example icons]

Upon touching one of them, the app will rearrange and the main area and prompt the user to load a component in each cell.

I am very confused as to how to achieve this in QML. I am aware of this post: [Select layout by user in QML application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25934695/select-layout-by-user-in-qml-application)

But it is 10 years old, none of the links work anymore and looking for relevant keyword in the current documentation confused me even more...

I'm not necessarily asking for ready made example but if someone could point me in the right direction, it would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[States](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-state.html) are definitely the way to go. Since you specifically mention that the different layouts need to be in separate files, I would just make each file its own State. The root file would instantiate all the objects and pick from the available states. But the state files would dictate where to position everything.

Here's a quick and easy example. It starts with a blue rectangle on the left and a green rectangle on the right. But if you click on it, the rectangles swap positions. Hopefully that's enough to get you pointed in the right direction for what you're trying to do.

main.qml

```
Item {
    id: parentRect
    width: 640
    height: 480

    property int stateIndex: 0

    states: [
        Layout1 { id: layout1 },
        Layout2 { id: layout2 }
    ]

    Component.onCompleted: {
        state = states[stateIndex].name;
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: blueRect
        width: parent.width / 2
        height: parent.height
        color: "blue"
        border.width: 20
        border.color: "yellow"
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: greenRect
        width: parent.width / 2
        height: parent.height
        color: "green"
        border.width: 20
        border.color: "red"
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            parentRect.stateIndex = !parentRect.stateIndex;
            parentRect.state = parentRect.states[parentRect.stateIndex].name;
        }
    }
}
```

Layout1.qml

```
State {
    name: "blueOnLeft"
    AnchorChanges {
        target: blueRect
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: undefined
    }

    AnchorChanges {
        target: greenRect
        anchors.left: undefined
        anchors.right: parent.right
    }
}
```

Layout2.qml

```
State {
    name: "blueOnRight"

    AnchorChanges {
        target: blueRect
        anchors.left: undefined
        anchors.right: parent.right
    }

    AnchorChanges {
        target: greenRect
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: undefined
    }
}
```